# Separate a date column with python, pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

You will find my python code below. 
Why am I unable to separate the column "date" please.

Separating the "close" column is easy. But "date" gives me an error:

```
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
 "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
 "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in
 pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
 "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in
 pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: 'date'
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

start_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 20)

panel_data = data.DataReader('GE', 'iex', start_date, end_date)
list(panel_data)
print(panel_data)
close = panel_data['close'].head(10)
print(close)
cls = close[0]

print(cls)
plt(close[0])
plt.show()
```

The list(panel_data) gives me the list of columns and values where the "date" column is at the end of the list of columns and is kind of attached/joined with the "volume" column like so: "open     high      low    close     volumedate" which is strange since when I print the panel_data the "date" column is at the beginning.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to post images so I rely on your imagination. 
Why is it such a problem to separate that column from the entire dataset, please?

Comment: You might remove the commented-out code from the body of your question, to limit the code in your question to just what's essential.

Comment: Are you sure you have the "date" column? From the error message it looks like you don't.

Comment: `date` is probably your index? Use `df.reset_index()` first or access thru `df.index` instead of `date`

Comment: Bingo! date was my index, I just didn't realize that since it's being displayed as if it was just another column. Now. I nee the data_panel.index be on the Y axis of the plot, and the "close" data on the X axis on the plot. However, there is 10 entries for the "close" column and 13 for the index. How do I limit the number of index values to 10 so it matches the number of values in the "close" column please?  Error: print(list(panel_data.index).head(10))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'